# Pause calculation at each row

Tags: r

I am trying to find a method in R to do a calculation on each row of a dataframe, but make it so that the script pauses after each row.

So, as an example, I would like to add a third column to the following dataframe (called df1)

```
Var1 Var2
1    2
1    2
1    3
1    3
1    3
```

I would do something like:

```
df1$Var3 <- df1$Var1 + df1$Var2
```

Which would result in:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
1    2    3
1    2    3
1    3    4
1    3    4
1    3    4
```

So what I want to do is that R pauses for, say 1 second, after calculating each row of Var3. For example using something similar as: Sys.sleep()

The reason I need this is that I would apply this principle to a script that calls an api that only accepts a select number of requests per second (Google Maps using the package ggmap). My script in ggmap experiences some unexpected errors and I want to make sure it's not an overload of requests, but I can't make the pauses work. So I first want to see how this works in a simple example.

Thank you in advance and do let me know if you require more information.

Comment: Simple example: `for(i in 1:10) {Sys.sleep(1); print(i)}` replace the `print` statement with your row assignment. and the `1:10` with `1:nrow(df1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
  for(i in 1:length(df1$Var1)){Sys.sleep(1)
        df1$Var3[i] = df1$Var1[i] + df1$Var2[i]}
```